# Android 5 : Error when deleting a file in sdcard using DocumentFile

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to port my app to use the new api DocumentFile. I have implemented calling the new intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Then the code

```
Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
DocumentFile folder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, treeUri);
folder.listFiles[0].delete(); // THIS IS NOT DELETING the correct directory.
```

How is it failing? I select a folder in the sdcard, e.g. /storage/sdcard1/temp. I have checked that folder.listFile[0] returns something like /storage/sdcard1/temp/test, BUT the folder that is deleted is /storage/sdcard1/temp when I would expect that it was /storage/sdcard1/temp/test.

What is going wrong?

Regards,
Francis.

Comment: Have you added permission?

Comment: yes of course, permission is there. App is perfectly working (reading and writing to external sdcard) before android 4.4. I am just working on the new API for android 5 (which is a nightmare).